# Writing down the KKT optimality conditions

Tags: numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

Consider the problem

Minimize  $(1/2)\times{x}^{T}\times Q\times x+{P}^{T}\times x$
    Subject to $(1/2)\times {x}^{T}\times P\times x+{d}^{T}\times x≤r$
    Where Q and P are n×n matrices, P is positive semi-definite, and r is a scalar.
    I would like to know on how to write down the KKT optimality conditions for the problem

Comment: Am the beginner I so I need to know even the procedures,because the book am using does not have enough points on this

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: Unable to attempt.this concept is not yet clear to me,Could you also give where I can read more and get clear understanding on KKT optimality conditions for nonlinear programming

Comment: S. Boyd and L. Vandenberghe, Convex Optimization (http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) or D. P. Bertsekas Nonlinear Programming or a variety of other texts.